# java logging writing multiple times for each thread in polling system

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

threading polling system in java. and i have included logging for each thread separately. but the instance of fileappender not getting closed with thread. so in the next poll when thread comes there are two instance of fileappender so it is logging two times and again in next poll its logging three time and so on...

here is my code

```
public void run()
{

    String parent = "Autobrs", name = "Pool";
    name = name + poolId;
    String loggerName = parent + "." + name;
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(loggerName);

    DailyRollingFileAppender fileApp = new DailyRollingFileAppender();
    fileApp.setName("Autobrs." + loggerName + "_FileAppender");
    fileApp.setFile("c:\\java\\"+ name+".log");
    fileApp.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  (%0F:%L) %3x - %m%n"));
    fileApp.setThreshold(Level.toLevel("debug"));
    fileApp.setAppend(true);
    fileApp.activateOptions();
    log.addAppender(fileApp);
}
```

and i don't know how to handle this.
pls help..

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use poolId to seperate the logs. I would imagine it is the same for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since FileAppender inherits `close()` from Writeappender [as stated here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html), use

```
fileApp.close()
```

Comment: i already have tried this before. logging is fine(single time).
but it displaying an error. 

"log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [Autobrs.Autobrs.Pool3448_FileAppender]."

Answer (score 0):

```
String parent = "Autobrs", name = "Pool";
name = name + poolId;
String loggerName = parent + "." + name;
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(loggerName);
```

You might have memory leak here.  Logger.getLogger() will keep a reference to all loggers it created.

Best practice would be to have one file appender configured by a `main` thread and each run() can log the `poolId` (or whatever) in its message.

Have multiple threads writing to a common logger & appender.